# Facebook ads not working ionic 1

Tags: facebook, facebook-audience-network

My application was able to display facebook native ads, and suddenly it stopped working. It is showing facebook status as OK. But I am not able to get the data for ads. I am not getting ads even though I have logged into facebook account even with test account. But still ads are not working. Can you please let me know what would be the reason, facebook ads stopped working suddenly.